# Link has eventListener, I click on child it activates but I'm not getting the href

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following block of html, I have multiple similar elements, but this is a sample.

```
<a class="link-wrapper" href="smaplesite.com">
      <div class="content">
        <h2 class="heading">
              Emergencies
        </h2>
      </div>
    </a>
```

I then have the following event listener

```
var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'));

links.forEach(function (link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', handleLinkClick);
});

function handleLinkClick(e, link) {
    var url = e.target.href;
}
```

However, url is coming back as null as the target element is the h2. How do I get the link?

Comment: `smaplesite.com` is not a valid URL. It needs to include the protocol, like `http://` or `https://`. The way you have it now, the system would try to find a file on the current server called `smaplesite.com`.

Comment: Also, `Array.from()` is not necessary. You can use `.forEach()` on the collection returned from `.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the element that was clicked on (which in this case is probably the `<h2>`) and that element doesn't have an `href` attribute.

Use [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the element that the event handler was bound to.